# Adding a hyperlink to the WooCommerce email template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to add a hyperlink to the product image thumbnail that I have just added to my email template on Woocommerce.

This is the php code I used to add image:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_args', 'iconic_email_order_items_args', 10, 1 );

function iconic_email_order_items_args( $args ) {

    $args['show_image'] = true;
    $args['image_size'] = array( 50, 50 );

    return $args;
```

Now what I need to do is make the image clickable so that it redirects the user to the product page. I would appreciate any advice from someone with more experience.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

To add the product link to the image and to the item name add this code to the functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail', 'add_email_order_item_permalink', 10, 2 ); // Product image
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'add_email_order_item_permalink', 10, 2 ); // Product name
function add_email_order_item_permalink( $output_html, $item, $bool = false ) {
    // Only email notifications
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url() )
        return $output_html;

    $product   = $item->get_product();

    return '<a href="'.esc_url( $product->get_permalink() ).'">' . $output_html . '</a>';
}
```